# AWS Cloudformation - cannot set parameters group name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-dbparametergroup.html

and

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbclusterparametergroup.html

Unless I am doing it wrong - I cannot set parameters groups name via CF templates, while I can easily set it via GUI and via CLI (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/create-db-parameter-group.html).  Additionally, for whatever reason, db cluster parameters group expects a non-empty parameters.

Is there a way to pass both name and parameters via CloudFormation?

Comment: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/212

Answer (score 0):

For the name, add a tag called Name. For the parameters I end up just adding a unimportant setting to its default value:

```
  ParameterGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBParameterGroup
    Properties:
      ...
      Parameters:
        application_name: ''
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: "MyParameterGroupName"
```

Comment: @Laruent tried that as well, but that doesn't do the job.

Comment: @Łukasz Well it works perfectly on my side. Can you explain what's happening?

Comment: It just adds a tag, but the name is still auto-generated. I can drop a picture on friday.
It's not a big deal after all. Good thing is that the generated name contains cloudformation resource name, so in my case all I had to do is to modify some CLI calls to extract the name.
Anyway, thanks for your attention. Thumbs up for u.

Comment: I am seeing the same result for RDS and DBParameterGroup with a "Name" tag.  The tag is added, it is just not used for the ID in the user interface.

Comment: DBInstanceIdentifier can be used for RDS instance name, however, there does not appear to be a way to set the DBParameterGroup name. #Sad